# Constrained regression python with variables as constraints

Tags: python, constraints, regression

I'm attempting to run a constrained regression in Python, using the sm.GLM model and then the model.fit_constrained code.

I am feeding in two variables alongside two dummy variables, the dummies are what I am trying to constrain.  I want the two dummy variables coefficients multiplied by a weight to equal zero.

This works fine when I am multiply the coefficients by integer weights, as below

```
results = model.fit_constrained('BOATS * 1 + CARS * 0.5')
```

However, I want these integers to be variable, and depend on the proportion of my data with a 1 for each dummy variable.  I have calculated the proportions in the series SectorWgt, but cannot work out how to then feed it in to the model.fit_constrained code.

This has been my best attempt

```
results = model.fit_constrained('SIZE*int(SectorWgt.iloc[0])+VQMadj*int(SectorWgt.iloc[1])')
```

But then I get the error

```
patsy.PatsyError: unrecognized token in constraint
```

due to the

```
int(SectorWgt.iloc[0])
```

part of code.

Does anyone have any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
x = int(SectorWgt.iloc[0])
y = int(SectorWgt.iloc[1])

results = model.fit_constrained('SIZE*{}+VQMadj*{}'.format(x, y))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If using Python 3.6 or newer, you can take advantage of cleaner string interpolation syntax with Python's [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

```
constraint_str = f"SIZE*{int(SectorWgt.iloc[0])}+VQMadj*{int(SectorWgt.iloc[1])}"
results = model.fit_constrained(constraint_str)
```